# how can i automatically remove all log in code

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my project, there are many logs like image above. I must remove manually. Everyone can suggest for me a best way that I can remove line logs easily.

[image]

Comment: just refactor and safe delete your logUtils method

Comment: why remove ? you can print them in only debug mode . by adding check in  LogUtils. if(BuildConfig.DEBUG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use find and replace to empty string by regex with rule

```
^*LogUtils\.d\(.*
```